# Yii2 command controller function not executing in crontab in docker container

Tags: php, docker, cron, yii2-advanced-app

I have a yii2 application running in a docker container. Basically I have a command controller which makes inserts data into the table. When I `docker exec -it container bash` into the container and run `/usr/local/bin/php /app/yii target/test` it works. I can see new data entered into the database. However when i set up crontab with  `*/1 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /app/yii target/test`  which is to run every minute for test purpose, i don't see any database entry no any error. Anyone encountered this before and what could be the issue